# Does yogurt contain any B vitamins?

Tags: nutrition, vitamin-b

Recently, vitamin B information has been removed from yogurt labels.  I am not sure if it is (any longer) considered a reasonable source for B vitamins.

B vitamins thiamine (B1) riboflavin (B2) niacin (B3) pantothenic acid (B5) B6 biotin (B7) B12 and folic acid (folate) are all found in varying degrees in yogurt.  Or were.  B vitamins are no longer found on yogurt labels.

All of them are water soluble, so any processes involving draining water (done with some Greek yogurts) will remove some B vitamins.

Heat can also destroy thiamine, pantothenic acid, and folate.  I am not sure how much heat commercial yogurt is exposed to.

This is contrasted with milk, which seems to retain most of its B vitamins.  The presence or absence of B vitamins in yogurt impacts on the utility of yogurt as a food product.

http://www.beyondveg.com/tu-j-l/raw-cooked/raw-cooked-2e.shtml

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! Please take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help](https://health.stackexchange.com/help). currently I'm tempted to 'answer': Changing label laws (where?) does not 'remove' vitamins. What has your research revealed so far? If you can, please update your question with a bit more prior research and context, possibly with inspiration of [how to ask](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have heard that most commercial yogurt processes renders most of the B vitamins worthless.  This MAY be why they were removed from labeling.  I have contacted some yogurt manufacturers and they have inconsistent information even within their own databases.  So I am still trying to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Oh. That sounds *very* interesting. By all means, edit that and your other research into the question. As soon it makes (some) sense to you

Comment: Going from an obscure question to a good one? Nice.